# Adding ORDER BY after variable in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this line of code, which works perfectly:

```
$data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE HiveID=" . $HiveID) or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to reverse the order of my listing, so I tried adding the ORDER BY after WHERE. I tried the following code:

```
$data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE HiveID=" . $HiveID  . "ORDER BY Date DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

This code gave me the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY Date DESC' at line 1.

I am unaware of how I can get this to work, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know the MySQL extension has been deprecated, right? You should not be writing code with this extension. Use PDO or MySQLi instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a space after the open quotes.

Should be `. $hive . " ORDER BY...`

Comment: I though it was going to be something simple, but I didn't think it was something that small. Thank you for your help and very fast response.

Answer (score 1):

your query is  `HiveID=" . $HiveID  . "ORDER` which will be  like `5ORDER`  (if hiveid is 5) so it wont give you result there must be a space before the `ORDER` try

```
"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE HiveID=" . $HiveID." ORDER BY Date DESC"
```

or

```
"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE HiveID='".$HiveID."' ORDER BY Date DESC"
```